# Copy of Typo3 folder on same server results in white screens

Tags: typo3

I'm trying to move a Typo3 installation like:

www/website/typo3/ to www/typo3/

Moving the folder results in a white screen though...
After downloading the complete page and uploading it to the other location same error.

Any suggestions how to deal with it?

Error Log:
Tue Apr 29 12:11:56 2014] [error] [client XXX] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in *[...]*/index.php on line 37

[Tue Apr 29 12:11:56 2014] [error] [client XXX] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in *[...]*/index.php on line 37

[Tue Apr 29 12:11:56 2014] [error] [client XXX] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in *[...]*/index.php on line 37

Comment: Go to Install Tool and check access permisions to required folders, also check server's error logs to find more clues

Comment: What do you mean by access permission to required folders? Basic Configuration -> Directories are all green and writable.

Comment: Ach didn't see additional error logs before, they are suggesting that you have PHP version lower then 5.3 - check it with phpinfo(), maybe your provider allows to set different PHP version per vhost/folder and the default is 5.2 (or something)

Comment: Ahh that could do the trick... There is a .htaccess providing a higher PHP version within www/website. Thanks

Comment: Could you add the actual solution as answer and then accept it? Thanks.